# Best method to implement many layout(XML) in an Android app

Tags: android, layout

I am very new to Android development and I'm trying to create a calculator with different layouts for different kinds of mathematical problem solving. 
So if I add around 100 formulas starting different activities isn't an option I guess. So what will be the best method to implement this idea?

Currently I plan to make different XML layouts(100 for 100 formulas) and use LayoutInflater all in one single activity. What do you guys recommend?

Comment: Not sure why you need 1 layout per formula, but if you have multiple layouts needed, what you suggest is what I would do.  I'd consider the whole 1 layout per formula issue, though -- know of any other calculators that do that? ;)

Comment: What will be the solution to the 1 layout per formula problem? Is there any way to strip down the number of layouts needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). One single activity with one single fragment. Each time you switch to a different formula, simply change the layout used in the fragment and show it. An approach (maybe not the best one) is use [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29) and in [onCreateView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29) method choose the layout you want to use.